# How to secure TensorFlow Serving API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

As a serving solution for production environments, does TensorFlow Serving include any options for securing it's REST API?

I can run-up a REST API endpoint by following these instructions https://github.com/tensorflow/serving#serve-a-tensorflow-model-in-60-seconds

But how can I now restrict access to that API endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, TF serving does not have a ready-made solution for this. But, if you are using serving your models via kubernetes, you can use [network policies](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/network_policy).